# Odoo 10: Showing error [object with reference: product_id - product.id]

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am working on a Expenses Module, but currently stuck at this error:

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:

- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: account_id - account.id]

**Here's my expense line**
[image: Expense Line]

**Here's the expense report that I've tried to post to journal entries**
[image: Expense Report]

I follow the list of Chart of Account (CoA) and Journal that are on Odoo Demo, so any ideas how to fix that **without configuring it in Python**? If it is needed, show me how to install the Python etc